# Assertion failure in -[SWRevealView layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, swrevealviewcontroller

*The difference from the suggested question is that I'm not using containsString: directly, but need to find where it is used.

On iOs 7 I'm getting an error:

> 2015-09-08 20:23:06.577 MyProject[2161:607] *** Assertion failure in -[SWRevealView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
>   2015-09-08 20:23:06.580 MyProject[2161:607] -[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf6c1b0
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

I know that containsString: appeared only in iOs 8, but I'm sure that I didn't use it. 'containsString' search in workplace shows nothing. Highlighted string is in 'main.m' file, so it tells me nothing.

Could you please tell me how can I find the place where containsString: is called?

Comment: Look at the stack trace from the crash to see what is calling `containsString:`.

Comment: Do you have breakpoints enabled on Objective-C exceptions in Xcode? If no, enable them, then look at the stack trace when it hits.

Comment: I added some more details on error. Nothing suggested helps, so may be I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm stuck in "Assertion failure", could you check SWRevealViewController.m's layoutSubviews method whether it includes [super layoutSubviews]?

Comment: @EDUsta, No, it doesn't

Comment: Do you mind adding it and re-build the project?

Comment: @EDUsta Wow! That helped! Still have no idea where is the method containsString: called, but adding a [super layoutSubviews] helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, for others to know, you should answer your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWRevealViewController.m's layoutSubviews method should include [super layoutSubviews]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a symbolic breakpoint for containsString as well as reading the trace in the console log. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. The result is still the same.

Comment: That is all that I got in console. Just these three lines. I'm not even sure that all of them relate t problem.